# Presto/Trino can't read Hive views

Tags: hive, hiveql, aws-glue, amazon-emr, presto

I have been trying to query some really simple Hive views using Glue Data Catalog and Presto/Trino on EMR with no luck.
The error is either 'View not found' or 'Hive views not supported'. I have tried to configure Trino with the legacy and experimental ([as explained in this doc](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#hive-views)) but when I override the default behavior in Trino (which is to ignore the views), the trino-server service just does not start.

The views I try to read are really simple, they should be supported by either legacy or experimental mode, also, the language in which they are defined is ANSI SQL.

Is there a known incompatibility between the Data Catalog and Presto? Or maybe with EMR? I know the problem is not versions as I have used multiple to test this behavior and it's always the same issue.

Update -> The create view statement I receive from Hive is something like this for all my views, only ANSI SQL is used:

```
CREATE VIEW `schema`.`view` AS
select
    `table`.`col1`,
    `table`.`col2`,
    `table`.`col3`
from
    `schema`.`table`
where
    table.datetime = '20220623'
```

Update -> I was able to read view using Trino once I applied this configuration in EMR Software Settings under `trino-connector-hive`  `"hive.views-execution.enabled": "true"` but I still can't query views using Presto

```
[
    {
        "classification": "presto-connector-hive",
        "properties": {
            "hive.metastore.glue.datacatalog.enabled": "true",
            "hive.views-execution.enabled": "true"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: If your Hive view definition has just ANSI SQL then it works otherwise you have to translate HQL to SQL and then try again.